# How to place DT elements side by side?

Tags: css

This:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZcdkT/1/

Renders:

```
DT-nameA
DD-definitionA 1

DT-nameB
DD-definitionB 1
DD-definitionB 2
```

I wish to have this:

```
DT-nameA                 DT-nameB
DD-definitionA 1         DD-definitionB 1 DD-definitionB 2
```

I've tried with display inline, float, clear... I can't figure this out.
Anyone ?

**Update:**
Inside the anchors, I may have different size images like this, hence, they don't really get side by side:

http://jsfiddle.net/j6Ute/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate DLs are the only way to achieve this because you need an extra wrapper element: http://jsfiddle.net/David_Knowles/j6Ute/

```
<div id="links-logolinks">
    <dl>
        <dt>Support</dt>
        <dd><a href="">support 1</a></dd>
    </dl>
    <dl>
        <dt>Partners</dt>
        <dd><a href="">Partner 1</a></dd>
        <dd><a href="">Partner 2</a></dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not mention it, but I'm using images with different heights on dd anchors, so they can't really stay "side by side".

Comment: Just checked. That's not exactly the end result wanted. dd should be side by side as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what I am missing :-) You have everything you need to do this don't you?

Comment: On your fiddle /4, you missed a display inline-block on dd, corrected on /5. So, I have everything now. Thanks.